# How does Treize survive the train wreck at the end of Allison & Lillia?

Tags: allison-and-lillia

In the final episode of Allison & Lillia, Treize lets go of the ladder to deal with "prisoner #42" just as the train runs off a cliff.

[image]

He comes back in the final scene to greet Lillia. But how in the world does he survive the fall?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to rephrase it, but you may want to edit your title to be less spoiler-y.

Comment: I could remove the "train wreck" from the title. But I'm not sure it does much though. Either way, the title is gonna give away that *something* happens at the end.

Comment: I was going to suggest "What happens to Treize during the wreck at the end of Allison & Lillia?"

Comment: I'm not sure that's any less spoiler-y... hmm...